# Can I detect month change on UIDatePicker?

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

I have a UIDatePicker with Inline style (showing as a calendar). I have an endpoint where I get the available dates for a month, so I would like to detect when the month that is showing is changed. I've tried all kinds of things, even add a target for the `.allEvents` event, but nothing seems to trigger it.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You should attach an IBAction to the valueChanged event for the picker.

(You could do that in Interface Builder, or by calling `addTarget(_:action:for:)` on the picker.)

That action will get called any time the user changes **any** part of the date. You'd then need to track the previous date and detect a change of month yourself.

Answer (score -2):

If you're using a view model, you could easily handle this through that:

Run the below in a Playground to see what I mean:

```swift
final class ViewModel {

    var selectedDateChanged: ((Date) -> Void)?

    var selectedDate: Date {
        didSet {
            selectedDateChanged?(selectedDate)
        }
    }

    init(selectedDate: Date = .now) {
        self.selectedDate = selectedDate
    }
}

let viewModel = ViewModel()
viewModel.selectedDateChanged = { date in
    // now you have the fact that it changed
    // and the new value to use, checking the month
    print(date)
}

viewModel.selectedDate = .now
```

Comment: In fact, even without a view model you can still do this, I'm just always thinking about testability which using the handler directly on a view controller may not give you